# Flask jinja2 retrieve value of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask with Jinja2 templates, how can I retrieve value from a select box using Jinja2 or using Java script + Jinja2 variable and use it?

Python side:

```
@app.route('/')
def dependent():
    fruits= {'apple':100,'orange':80,'mango':200}
    return render_template('select.html',fruits=fruits)
```

HTML+Jinja2 side

```
<form>
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    {% for fruit in fruits.keys() %}
        <option value="{{ fruit }}"> {{ fruit }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<p>fruits[{{fruit}}]</p>

</form>
```

I would like to display the price of the selected fruit next to the selection but I'm unable to retrieve the selected value and use it. I know the final '< p>' tag is incorrect. How to do this properly?

PS: I'm completely ignorant regarding JS, jQuery and Ajax

## Update:

```
<script>
          var selectTag = document.getElementById('fruit')
          var pTag = document.getElementById('fruit-binding')
          function val() {
            pTag.innerText = fruits[selectTag.value];
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this using javascript. One way to do it, to add your fruit price as the value of the option tag, and use javascript to display this value of the selected item into the p tag.

```
<form>
  <select onchange="val()" name="fruit" id="fruit">
    {% for fruit in fruits %}
    <option value="{{ fruits[fruit] }}">{{ fruit }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <p id="fruit-binding"></p>
</form>
<script>
  var selectTag = document.getElementById('fruit')
  var pTag = document.getElementById('fruit-binding')
  pTag.innerText = selectTag.value
  function val() {
    pTag.innerText = selectTag.value
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually instead of a p tag, I want to update a table entry. Can you help how to do that if its  <td> ? @Gaz Zhao

Comment: That is the same logic, assign an id to your <td> tag, and use document.getElementById to grab it, and update its inner text.

Comment: In this example you have used actual values. I have a dictionary of fruits and I'm not able to access the price of fruit using the selectTag.value as indexer. 
Please see the update in question
This doesn't work. Can you tell me how to make accessing the dictionary work inside javascript?

Comment: It is not that straightforward to pass variables from javascript into jinja blocks, one way to solve your problem is to embed the prices inside the option tag, and use javascript to show it in the p tag based on selection. I updated the answer.